# I am the stuff of science fiction... what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the stuff of science fiction,
>  yet I exist fairly abundantly in the real world. 
> I am found in anime and even featured in one, 
> and a medication of no relation bears my name.
>  While by definition I look like you, 
> I look nothing like you when you hold me in your hand.

**What am I?**

#### HINT 1:

> The medication name matches mine exactly

#### HINT 2:

> Lines 2 and 6 are related; while some of me in the real world match my definition, those of me that you hold in your hand (which are by far the most prevalent today) don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are (an)

> Android.

I am the stuff of science fiction,

> (in which the term generally means a human-looking robot)

yet I exist fairly abundantly in the real world.

> (in which the term generally means Google's mobile-device operating system or one of the devices running it)

I am found in anime and even featured in one,

> (sorry, I know nothing about anime, but surely there must be lots with androids in)

and a medication of no relation bears my name.

> Methyltestosterone.

While by definition I look like you,

> An android is a *humanoid* robot.

I look nothing like you when you hold me in your hand.

> Most people don't much resemble their mobile phones.

Comment: Well done, sir! Can anyone name the anime I am featured in? It's an older one :)

Comment: Maybe the anime is *Astro Boy*?

Comment: @ShaneHsu correct! That fills out the fourth criteria that Gareth is a bit weak/guessing on :)

Answer (score 1):

You are

> a ROBOT?

*I am the stuff of science fiction,

yet I exist fairly abundantly in the real world.*

> Robots are a staple of science fiction, but they also exist in reality.

*I am found in anime and even featured in one,*

> I know nothing about anime, but a quick Google suggests there's something called [mecha anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha_anime_and_manga) which is about robots.

*and a medication of no relation bears my name.*

> Searching for "robot" and "medication" led me to [this](http://www.aesynt.com/robot-rx).

*While by definition I look like you,

I look nothing like you when you hold me in your hand.*

> The stereotypical robot is human-shaped, but one small enough to fit in your hand probably wouldn't be.

Comment: I suppose it's more of letter shape related than the meaning of the words. Maybe "l" or "1". Robots is obviously not "By definition I look like you", Androids may be.

Comment: Good try, but that's not it. "Robot RX" dispenses medication, but is not a medication itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A clone?

I am the stuff of science fiction,
yet I exist fairly abundantly in the real world.

> We clone many types of creatures, just not humans (yet)

I am found in anime and even featured in one,

> Perhaps Pokemon? The clone of Mew, being Mewtwo is featured heavily in the first movie.

and a medication of no relation bears my name.

> I found the medication ZOPICLONE with a quick google search

While by definition I look like you, 
I look nothing like you when you hold me in your hand.

> If you meet a clone, it will be much younger, and look very little like you, especially because it would have different scarring patterns, finger prints, etc. Especially if it is small enough to hold in your hand, it will be a fetus, which looks very different from a (presumably) adult human.